# In a follow-up email, should I express my interest or ask for the state of the application?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, applications, email, follow-up

Recently I have applied to a big company for a position that I'm really interested in and I think I have the right skillset and the experience. But I know that besides the qualifications, the application review depends on the 1-2 minutes that the HR staff spend on each application as the first filter. So, I've experienced and also have heard many stories about candidates being early dismissed even though their profile was a good match for the position.

I have decided to send a follow-up email to the hiring manager to increase my chances of being noticed in the pile of resumes. However, I'm not sure if the email should be sent like I'm only asking about the state of the application, or boldly express my interest in the position and directly asking for an interview with the hiring manager in parallel to the submitted application?

Comment: May make no difference... have heard that first skim is based on school leaving results or some arbitrary hurdle just to get the pile of applications down to a more reasonablexamount and they take the risk of loosing good ones.

Comment: @SolarMike, what's your point? no follow-up email is useful or necessary for any application?

Comment: How much time has passed since you sent your application and now?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, Then what are these tons of information online and offline about how to write a follow-up email/letter about? Are you saying that the concept of a follow-up letter for a submitted application is just a global illusion?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I see! So even after 2 weeks are passed since the submission, not follow-up email (or whatever you call it) is not recommended? Just waiting until you hear something or nothing from them?

Answer (score 1):

> I have decided to send a follow-up email to the hiring manager to increase my chances of being noticed in the pile of resumes

I don't think this premise of yours is always true.

If they already told you to wait for them, or something similar, sending such email may be perceived as eager/too soon, distract them from the review process, etc.

It will be ok to send a follow-up email in case it has passed some time between you last heard from them (no rule for this, but at least a week or two).

Anyways, if you decide to send an email I think you can convey both your interest on the job and to probe about the state of the application. A phrasing I can think of is:

> Hello [name]. I'm writing to see if there is anything else you need me to submit or send that you require, so I can give it to you promptly. I would also like to thank you for the opportunity; I'm very excited about the job and the topics it involves, as those are subjects I enjoy very much...

Feel free to modify it to your liking and add reasons why you consider yourself a great fit.

What I wouldn't do is to *"directly asking for an interview with the hiring manager"*, as you mentioned. That would be bypassing the recruitment process, and nothing the interviewer/staff can do for you in that aspect. It may come up as a bit rude or demanding.

Regardless, it's very important you don't go all in with this single offer. Consider applying to other jobs as a security measure just in case this one doesn't result in an offer.

Comment: What do you say about this article?
https://zety.com/blog/how-to-follow-up-on-a-job-application
Is it total crap?!

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't.

If they are processing your application, then your response may be viewed as being desperate or annoying, and they may reconsider whatever decision that they have made regarding your hiring. If they haven't considered hiring you, this would be just another reason for them not to do so.

You obviously want to work for them. You need to wait for them to contact you and you need to develop a backup plan (or plans) in case the answer that you are seeking isn't the answer that you receive.